# Change link by checking a radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have to modify `<meta property="og:url" content="http://a42de5e.contato.site/agradecimento">` <- when someone checks 'yes' in a radio button, is there any way I could do it using JavaScript?

```html
<div class="form-group">

  <h4 class="control-label" data-selector="h4">Would you support us?</h4>

  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="Yes" value="Yes">Sim</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="No" value="No ">Não</label>

</div>
```

I tried something using "getElementByID" but I'm not sure if it's possible because it's a meta tag

Comment: The answers, that you can modify that tag, are good — but will it have any effect? `meta` tags are directives to the browser; will the browser act on a change, or is it only effective at load time? The open-graph protocol is mainly used by search engines and link previews, read from the page "at-rest"; Will changing `og:url` have any effect when a human is looking the page? (unless you're persisting it back to the server) `og:url` in particular is _"[The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its permanent ID in the graph](http://ogp.me/#metadata)"_ — does changing it make sense?

Comment: This looks like XY Problem. Can you write why you need to change that meta tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By giving the specified `meta` tag an `ID` and the `input[type="checkbox"]` element an `ID` you can achieve your goal.

In my answer the `meta` tag's content is set based on the `input[type="checkbox"]` state: if it's checked then the new url is set to the content property, otherwise, if it's unchecked we fall back to the initial content of the `meta` tag.

> In the snippet I gave an `id="opengraph"` to the `meta` tag, and an `id="toggle"` to the `input[type="checkbox"]`.

```js
// declaring  variables so we make our task easier.

/**
* referencing the 'meta' tag by the 'og' variable.
* referencing the 'checkbox' tag by the 'toggle' variable.
* the 'oldOG' variable stores the initial content of the 'meta' tag, so when the 'checkbox' gets unchecked the initial content is set to the 'meta' tag.
* the 'newOG' variable stores the new content(url), change it per your requirements.
**/
var og = document.getElementById('opengraph'),
    toggle = document.getElementById('toggle'),
    oldOG = og.getAttribute('content'),
    newOG = 'add your new link here';
// adding a change event listener to the 'checkbox', and alter the content of the 'meta' tag based on the 'checkbox' state(if checked => newOG is set, if unchecked => the initial content(oldOG) is set).
toggle.addEventListener('change', function() {
  og.setAttribute('content', (this.checked === true) ? newOG:oldOG);
  
  // just for the demo, remove the next line in production phase.
  console.log('content: ' + og.getAttribute('content'));
});
```

```html
<meta id="opengraph" property="og:url" content="http://a42de5e.contato.site/agradecimento">
<span>toggle the meta tag's content<input type="checkbox" id="toggle" /></span>
```

Here's some useful links:

> [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) about `addEventListener` method.
>
> [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/change) about the `change` event.
>
> [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) about `getElementById` method.
>
> [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) about `getAttribute` method.
>
> [Learn more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) about `setAttribute` method.

Hope I pushed you further.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you needed a vanilla javascript answer but in jquery you could probably do something like this `$("meta[property='og\\:url']").attr("content", "your desired string");` to change the content dynamically

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible for meta tags too. Here I used regular `getElementById` to get necessary elements, `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` to make operations with meta value. I also logged to console both old and new values of `content` attribute to ensure, that it changes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta id="meta" property="og:url" content="http://a42de5e.contato.site/agradecimento">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="form-group">
    <h4 class="control-label" data-selector="h4">Would you support us?</h4>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input id="yes" type="radio" name="Yes" value="Yes">
      Sim
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
      <input id="no" type="radio" name="No" value="No">
      Não
    </label>
  </div>

  <script>
    const el = document.getElementById('yes');
    const meta = document.getElementById("meta");
    el.onclick = function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        console.log('Old meta content: ' + meta.getAttribute("content"));
        meta.setAttribute("content", "NEW_META_CONTENT");
        console.log('New meta content: ' + meta.getAttribute("content"));
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to change the element value, right?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta id="ogurl" property="og:url" content="http://a42de5e.contato.site/agradecimento">

</head>
<body>
<div class="form-group">

  <h4 class="control-label" data-selector="h4">Would you support us?</h4>

  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="change" value="Y">Sim</label>
  <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="change" value="N">Não</label>

</div>

<script>
$(function() {
  
  $('input[name=change]').change(function() {
    if(this.value === 'Y') {  document.getElementById("ogurl").setAttribute("content", "http://google.com");
    console.log(document.getElementById("ogurl"));
    }

  })
  
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```